# variable not being read correctly

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following in a bash script:

```
target="-h1.2.3.4 -P3307"
user="-uusername"
pass="-ppassword"

mysql ${target} ${user} ${pass} -se"SHOW DATABSES;"
```

This works fine, except that it connects to Port 3306 and not 3307. How can I make it read `${target}` correctly?

Without splitting `target` into two separate variables.

---

If I manually run

`mysql -h1.2.3.4 -P3307 -uusername -ppassword`

then it works fine, so that is what I am trying to achieve. It is almost as if MySQL is ignoring the `-P3307` and using the default `3306`.

I also tried putting it all in one variable, and that doesn't work either (it ignores the Port, Username and Password).

---

It looks like the problem is that MySQL is interpreting the `$target` value as if it is one thing. If I switch around Port and Host I get:

```
target="-P3307 -h1.2.3.4"
mysql ${target} ${user} ${pass} -se"SHOW DATABSES;"
```

I get:

```
Unknown suffix ' ' used for variable 'port' (value '3307 -h1.2.3.4')
mysql: Error while setting value '3307 -h1.2.3.4' to 'port'
```

So I don't know if that is a MySQL problem or a Linux problem?

Comment: Search terms: "shell quoting variables", put them inside double quotes, also https://www.shellcheck.net/ might be useful.

Comment: bash is passing "-P3307" as the second parameter to mysql; quoting it as phk suggests would just turn mysql's arg1 into "-h1.2.3.4 -P3307".  I'm not familiar enough with mysql to know: (1) is there other overriding configuration for host 1.2.3.4 that determines the port, or (2) does mysql want a space after `-P` and before `3307`?

Comment: if you echo, what is the output ?

echo mysql ${target} ${user} ${pass} -se"SHOW DATABSES;"

Comment: If I echo it, it looks fine `mysql -h1.2.3.4 -P3307 -uusername -ppassword -se"SHOW DATABASES"`